# How to retrieve Firestore Document Data based on the currently logged in user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase/Firestore project that stores data from a QR Code scanner and later displays all the previously scanned items in a history list manner. I used this line to detrmine the stream, `stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').where('user_id', isEqualTo:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).orderBy('Created_On', descending: true).snapshots(),`

Without the `.where('user_id', isEqualTo:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)` condition the list outputs all the previously scanned data without the filter of the specific items the user scanned.

With the `.where('user_id', isEqualTo:FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)` condition, the list displays correctly for a Second then displays a `CircularProgressIndicator` forever.

I want to display the correct data that the user has scanned based on the user ID, Please help me.

The code to display the list of the transactions:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Transactions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TransctionsState createState() => _TransctionsState();
}

class _TransctionsState extends State<Transactions> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Transactions"),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('product')
                .where('user_id', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                .orderBy('Created_On', descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasError)
                {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.docs;
                return ListView(
                    children: documents.map((docValue) =>
                        Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.history, color: Colors.grey,),
                            title: Text(docValue["ScannedProd"]),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                docValue["Created_On"].toDate().toString()),
                          ),
                        )).toList());
              }
            ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore Collection and document structure
[image: Firestore 1]

[image: Firestore 2]

Then you can use this to get the list without querying

```
final String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users/$uid/Product').orderBy('Created_On', descending: true).snapshots(),
```

Re written code:

```
class Transactions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TransctionsState createState() => _TransctionsState();
}

class _TransctionsState extends State<Transactions> {
  final String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Transactions"),
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Users/$uid/Product')
                .orderBy('Created_On', descending: true)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData)
              {
                final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = snapshot.data.docs;
                return ListView(
                    children: documents.map((docValue) =>
                        Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.history, color: Colors.grey,),
                            title: Text(docValue["ScannedProd"]),
                            subtitle: Text(
                                docValue["Created_On"].toDate().toString()),
                          ),
                        )).toList());
              }else if (snapshot.hasError){
                return Container(); //error handel it
              } else{
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
            }
        ));
  }
}
```

The above will return all the QR stored by the user.

Comment: The ```CircularProgressIndicator``` is now gone but it just displays a blank screen with no data... Can You Please explain what is happening in the ```collection()``` parenthesis?